# Get the array object based on matching key in groovy

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

I have an HTTP request in the Jmeter, for which I am getting a JSON response consisting of an array.

Response:

```
{
    "Success": true,
    "RoomRecordsCount": 0,
    "RoomBookings": [],
    "DeskRecordsCount": 1,
    "DeskBookings": [
        {
            "BookingID": 569114,
            "BookingType": 2,
            "BookingStart": "11/07/2023 12:00 PM",
            "BookingEnd": "11/07/2023 23:59 PM",
            "TimeZoneOffSetInMins": 60,
            "TimeZone": "GMT Standard Time",
            "Status": 3,
            "AdditionalInformation": null,
            "FloorID": 0,
            "FloorName": "0",
            "CountryID": 9,
            "LocationID": 93,
            "LocationName": "AJ-LOC",
            "GroupID": 259,
            "GroupName": "AJ-GROUP",
            "DeskID": 29264,
            "DeskName": "Desk 2",
            "CanBeBooked": false,
            "DeskAttributes": null,
            "WSTypeId": 2,
            "WsTypeName": "MS Desk",
            "QRCodeEnabled": false,
            "bookMultipleDesk": true
        }
    ],
    "EditMiniSyncBooking": false,
    "Error": {
        "ErrorCode": 0,
        "ErrorDescription": ""
    }
}
```

This 'DeskBookings' can have multiple objects in its array. So I want only that object which matches with specific 'DeskID'

I wrote the groovy code in 'JSR223 PostProcessor'

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
def response = jsonSlurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
def json = JsonOutput.toJson(response.findAll{ it.DeskBookings.DeskID == '29264' });

vars.put("bookingId", json.BookingID);
```

Error:

```
2023-07-11 00:07:57,966 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: DeskBookings for class: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
```

Comment: Try `response.DeskBookings.find { it.DeskID == '29264' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need to do any scripting, you can get the `BookingID` using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)

[image]

If you still want to continue using Groovy consider following points:

1. Your `DeskID` is an integer, you need to remove quotation marks from there
2. There is no need to use JsonOutput
3. [vars.put()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#put(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) function expects 2 Strings and you're trying to put an integer there

You need to amend your code as follows:

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();

def response = jsonSlurper.parse(prev.getResponseData());

def deskBooking = response.DeskBookings.find {it.DeskID == 29264}

vars.put("bookingId", deskBooking.BookingID as String);
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and Producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple of problems:

- You should use .find from DeskBookings
- The DeskID is a number

Here is a little script to illustrate the changes.

```
import groovy.json.*

String json = '''
{
    "Success": true,
    "RoomRecordsCount": 0,
    "RoomBookings": [],
    "DeskRecordsCount": 1,
    "DeskBookings": [
        {
            "BookingID": 569114,
            "BookingType": 2,
            "BookingStart": "11/07/2023 12:00 PM",
            "BookingEnd": "11/07/2023 23:59 PM",
            "TimeZoneOffSetInMins": 60,
            "TimeZone": "GMT Standard Time",
            "Status": 3,
            "AdditionalInformation": null,
            "FloorID": 0,
            "FloorName": "0",
            "CountryID": 9,
            "LocationID": 93,
            "LocationName": "AJ-LOC",
            "GroupID": 259,
            "GroupName": "AJ-GROUP",
            "DeskID": 29264,
            "DeskName": "Desk 2",
            "CanBeBooked": false,
            "DeskAttributes": null,
            "WSTypeId": 2,
            "WsTypeName": "MS Desk",
            "QRCodeEnabled": false,
            "bookMultipleDesk": true
        }
    ],
    "EditMiniSyncBooking": false,
    "Error": {
        "ErrorCode": 0,
        "ErrorDescription": ""
    }
}
'''

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def response = jsonSlurper.parseText(json);
def desk = JsonOutput.toJson(response.DeskBookings.find{ it.DeskID == 29264 });

println(desk)
```

Comment: Oh! Blunder mistake...but now it is showing me :
2023-07-11 11:22:11,479 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BookingID for class: java.lang.String